# what is the purpose of @Component in OSGI factory implementations?

Tags: java, maven, osgi, apache-karaf, service-factory

I am trying to implement servicefactory using apache felix scr annotations.

```
@Component
@Service(serviceFactory = true)
@Properties(value = { @Property(name = "className", value = "interface1") })
public class Tinterfaceimpl1 implements Tinterface {

    @Override
    public void consumeService() {
        System.out.println("tinterfaceimpl1");
    }
}
```

Above code is working fine. But what is the purpose of @Component? Because i am trying to expose it as a service instead of both Component & Service. If i remove the @Component state is unsatisfied. IS it really mandatory for a factory to use both component and service?
pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>TinterfaceImpl</groupId>
    <artifactId>TinterfaceImpl</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <version>2.3.5</version>
                <!-- <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Import-Package>com.java.serviceeg.tinterface.Tinterface</Import-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration> -->
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.14.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-scr-scrdescriptor</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>scr</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        </build>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Felix SCR annotations -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.apache.felix.scr.annotations</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.apache.felix.scr</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>Tinterface</groupId>
                <artifactId>Tinterface</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <type>bundle</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <packaging>bundle</packaging>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is mandatory. It declares your class as a Component according to the Declarative Services specifcation. Without the `@Component` annotation, it is merely some class hanging around in your bundle.

Components *may* also be published as services, as in this example. But components do not *have* to be services -- instead they might expose some kind of external interface like a server socket or a GUI.

Comment: I am trying to expose a service,using ds, which requires Component annotation, otherwise it fails and service is unsatisfied state. Could you please why component annotation is required when i am going with simply a service?. Also could you please provide me the pointer for the above explanation .

Comment: My answer did explain why @Component is required. What you are writing is both a service *and* a component.

Comment: My question was not related to the above one. It's just service I am implementing(with ds). There it expects component annotation. Without the annotation the the service becomes unsatisfied.

Comment: That's because the @Component annotation is required. I don't know any more ways to state the same thing.

Comment: Hi, may i know what is the use of factory attribute in @component annotation.